# odroid/ubuntu - getting wlan to start

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

Im working with an 'odroid' fanless PC. The latest OS attempt on it is the stock Ubuntu 14.04 that comes with it. Have made some progress getting the networking (eth0) started but am having issues with the wireless.

Per `dmesg` I see this:

```
[    7.504855] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8192cu
[    7.570063] systemd-udevd[386]: renamed network interface wlan0 to wlan2
[    8.430903] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan2: link is not ready
```

But via `ipconfig wlan2` I'm seeing this:

```
wlan2 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <mac addr>
      inet addr:192.168.70.1  Bcast:192.168.70.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

In `/etc/network/interfaces.d/wlan` I have this:

```
auto wlan2
iface wlan2 inet static
address 192.168.70.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

The ultimate goal is to turn it into an access point using **dnsmasq** and (probably) **hostapd**. I disabled network-manager as it was trying too hard to 'help me' and kept undoing what I was working on.

Starting **hostapd** I get this message:

```
Configuration file: ./hostapd.conf
nl80211 driver initialization failed.
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan2 wasn't started
```

Seeing this I tried the instructions listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472794/hostapd-error-nl80211-could-not-configure-driver-mode). No change in status.

I know the adapter works as a WAP as I was able to get it working (mostly) using Debian. Further this command `iwconfig wlan0 mode master` works ok. Following this with `iw list` I get nothing back.

So clearly the WAP antenna / dongle isn't configured properly. I've never worked with Ubuntu before so I'm sure I've gone astray somewhere.  Suggestions on where to look?